# I can't open website on local by using "yarn start"

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-dom, chakra-ui

When I tried execute "yarn start", showing this command
[image]
Then I got this webpage
[image]
How do I do to fix this error? Please teach me!!
My home code I put here[image]

How do I do to fix this error? Please teach me!!

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text. For more information, please see the Meta FAQ entry [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors/285557#285557)

Answer (score 0):

In Next.js there is none `react-router-dom` (and its BrowserRouter, etc.). It has its own [router](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/router) solution and it is **file based**. Check [nextjs official documentation](https://nextjs.org/docs/routing/introduction). There is everything you need.

Comment: const Home: NextPage = () => {
  return (
      <ul>
          <Header />
          <li>
              <Link href="/aboutMe">About Me</Link>
          </li>
          <li>
              <Link href="/">Home</Link>
          </li>
          <li>
              <Link href="/skills">Skills</Link>
          </li>
      </ul>
  )
}
export default Home
I changed my code refering the website you show me but my localhost:3000 show me only 404